# No data in related table - artificial blank category DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have following questions.

**Table Sales:**

[image]

**Table Product:**

[image]

Table Sales is connected to table Product via Sales ID.

Table Sales contain 5 unique records, table Product contain only 3 of them. 2 are missing. Is there some way how to artificially create in Power BI missing category?

[image]

Comment: What's your current definition for *Amt Sales*? `Amt Sales = COUNTROWS(Sales)`, for example, will return an additional blank row, as required, whereas `Amt Sales = COUNTROWS(Products)` will not.

Comment: you are right. but I forgot to mention one more thing, sorry. table product contains also additional columns and I'm filtering visual based on value from one of the columns - e.g. column color = blue

Comment: Suggest you update your post to make it more realistic. Also, copiable data is better than pictures.